# getting unused variable warnings even though I am using the variables

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, unused-variables

In the following code, I get a token I am querying multiple databases which return `Future`. I want to do the next query based on the outcome of the previous one.

```
val result:Future[Result] = for{tokenOption:Option[UserToken] <- if(urlHost != "" && successUrlParameter != "" && failUrlParameter != "") {userTokenRepo.findOne(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))} else {Future.successful(None)}  //generator 1 - get token from database
                                    userOption:Option[User] <- if (tokenOption.isDefined) {userRepo.findOne(tokenOption.get.userKeys)} else {Future.successful(None)} //generator2. found token, look for corresponding user to which the token belongs
                                    modifiedUser:Option[User] <- if (userOption.isDefined) {confirmSignupforUser(userOption.get)} else Future.successful(None) //generator 3. found user and token. Update profile
                                    deletedToken:Option[UserTokenKey] <- if(modifiedUser.isDefined) {userTokenRepo.delete(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))} else Future.successful(None)
       }
         yield { //check if we have user and token and modified user here. If any is missing, return error else success
           if(urlHost == "" || successUrlParameter == "" || failUrlParameter == ""){//error in reading redirection url.
             InternalServerError(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Internal Server Error. Redirection missing ")))
           } else { //read redirection url, so can redirect with success or failure parameter
             println("db query results tokenOption: " + tokenOption + ", userOption: " + userOption + " : modifiedUserOption: " + modifiedUser + ", deletedToken: " + deletedToken)
             //all db ops other than deletinng token should be successful. Error in deletinng token is not a critical error from user perspective and thus should not affect signup verification
             if (tokenOption.isDefined && userOption.isDefined && modifiedUser.isDefined /*&& deletedToken.isDefined*/) {
               Redirect(s"${urlHost};${successUrlParameter}") //TODOM - pick from config
             }
             else {
               /*TODOM - when redirecting with error, can provide additional info why sign up failed*/
               Redirect(s"${urlHost};${failUrlParameter}") //TODOM - pick from config
             }
           }
         }
```

I have enabled `"-Xfatal-warnings"` and `-Ywarn-unused:locals` in compiler options. I am getting warning that `tokenOption`, `userOption`,`modifiedUser` and `deletedToken` are not used but I am using them (the next query is done if the `Option` returned by previous one `isDefined`.). Why am I getting the compiler warning?

```
Error:(410, 40) pattern var tokenOption in value $anonfun is never used; `tokenOption@_' suppresses this warning
       val result:Future[Result] = for{tokenOption:Option[UserToken] <- if(urlHost != "" && successUrlParameter != "" && failUrlParameter != "") {userTokenRepo.findOne(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))} else {Future.successful(None)}  //generator 1 - get token from database

Error:(411, 37) pattern var userOption in value $anonfun is never used; `userOption@_' suppresses this warning
                                    userOption:Option[User] <- if (tokenOption.isDefined) {userRepo.findOne(tokenOption.get.userKeys)} else {Future.successful(None)} //generator2. found token, look for corresponding user to which the token belongs
```

Comment: Is all this code really necessary to show the problem? Please reduce this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ManuChadha What version of scala are you using?

Comment: 2.12 I think. I need to check but am not near my machine at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug according to [Unused warning occurred even if the variable was used #11175](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11175). The following snippet

```
object Hello {
  for {
    a <- Option(1)
    b <- Option(2) if a == 1
  } yield a + b
}
```

reproduces the issue on my machine with Scala 2.12.8 and 2.13, but does not seem to occur with Scala 2.12.1, so I would suggest trying different versions and see which one works for you.

Comment: I am using 2.12.2. If I move to 2.12.1, then `-Ywarn-unused:locals` compiler option is not recognized which I suppose defeats my purpose.